# AWS CloudWatch Cross-Account Logging with EC2 Instance Profile

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-cloudwatch

When I originally setup CloudWatch, I created an EC2 Instance Profile to automatically grant access to write to the account's own CloudWatch service.  Now, I would like to consolidate the logs from several accounts into a central account.

I'd like to implement a simplified architecture that is based on [Centralized Logging on AWS](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/solutions/latest/centralized-logging/architecture.html). However, these logs will feed an on-premise ELK stack, so I'm only trying to implement the components outlined in red.  I would like to solve this without the use of Kinesis.

[image: simplified central logging on aws]

Either the CloudWatch Agent (CWAgent) doesn't support assuming a role or I can't wrap my mind around how to craft the EC2 Instance Profile to allow the CWAgent to assume a role in a different account.

**Logging Target (AWS Account 111111111111)**

IAM LogStreamerRole:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "AWS": [
          "arn:aws:iam::999999999999:role/EC2CloudWatchLoggerRole"
        ]
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
      "Condition": {}
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:*:*:*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Logging Source (AWS Account 999999999999)**

IAM Instance Profile Role:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Principal": {
        "Service": "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      },
      "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
    }
  ]
}
```

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/LogStreamerRole"
        }
    ]
}
```

The CWAgent is producing the following error:

```
/opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/logs/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.log:
2018-02-12T23:27:43Z E! CreateLogStream / CreateLogGroup with log group name Linux/var/log/messages stream name i-123456789abcdef has errors. Will retry the request: AccessDeniedException: User: arn:aws:sts::999999999999:assumed-role/EC2CloudWatchLoggerRole/i-123456789abcdef is not authorized to perform: logs:CreateLogStream on resource: arn:aws:logs:us-west-2:999999999999:log-group:Linux/var/log/messages:log-stream:i-123456789abcdef
    status code: 400, request id: 53271811-1234-11e8-afe1-a3c56071215e
```

It is still trying to write to its own CloudWatch service, instead of to the central CloudWatch service.

Comment: I have to admit, I went ahead and stood up a POC using Kinesis and it is nice.  The sub-accounts can still review their own CloudWatch Logs and a copy is sent to a single Kinesis stream.

Answer (score 0):

From the logs, I see that the instance profile is used.

> arn:aws:sts::999999999999:assumed-role/EC2CloudWatchLoggerRole/i-123456789abcdef

Just add the following to the /etc/awslogs/awscli.conf to assume the LogStreamerRole role.

role_arn = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/LogStreamerRole
credential_source=Ec2InstanceMetadata

Comment: Do these same options apply to the unified cwagent?
It's configuration file is /opt/aws/amazon-cloudwatch-agent/etc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.toml.  I couldn't find the options you gave under the old agent's documentation either, so maybe these are hidden options?

Comment: This was not mentioned in the documents. Can you add the role to this config file? I'm assuming the "cwagent" should pick up the role. However, it is not documented anywhere. [installation-directory/doc/amazon-cloudwatch-agent-schema.json](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch-Agent-Configuration-File-Details.html)   
`
"agent": {
   "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
   "region": "us-west-1",
  ** "role_arn": "arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/LogStreamerRole"**
  }
`